# Newton's method chaotic dynamical system 1

Tags: newton-raphson, chaos-theory

I need your help to understand the below question.

I have the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-3x^2-5x-9$ with initial condition $x_0=4$. Asking to compute the first iterates with Newton's method, what is the limit?

I can find the iterates, I also see that Newton's method failed, but I don't get it when ask "what is the limit"?

Anyone has any experience?
Thank you all.

Comment: What are you looking to find? $p(x) = 0$?

Comment: So I just tried this in Matlab and I get convergence, not large oscillation or chaos or whatever. So I think you made a mistake.

Comment: ok, and even it is converge, what means what is the limit?
do you have any site to check how to try in matlab? thanks

Comment: I don't think they expect you to write the limit down in closed form, just approximate it from the iterations. The exact form (which can be found using the cubic formula) is an ugly expression involving both cube and square roots.

Comment: @Moo: this is exactly the exercise: 
This is an example showing that Newton method could fail to compute the roots of a polynomial. Compute the expression of the Newton Method applied to the polynomial   $p(x)=x^3−3x^2−5x−9$ . Compute the first iterates of the Newton method with initial condition x0 = 4, what is the limit?